# How to execute a function in the cell below every column of a specific range?

Tags: vba, loops, excel

So, this is what I wrote so far:

```
Sub somme()
    Dim a, i As Integer, Data, Rng As Range
    a = InputBox("How many cells for the square?")
    Set Data = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(a - 1, a - 1))

    For Each cell In Data
        cell.Value = Int((100 + 100 + 1) * Rnd - 100)
    Next
    For i = 1 To a
        Set Range(ActiveCell + i, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)) _
            .Offset(1, 0).Value = "=SUM(R[-a]C:R[-1]C)"
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to sum every column in the cell right below, for any sized range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your same approach, you can add the sum by using the built-in WorksheetFunction.Sum and just looking up by the end of each column:

```
Set sums = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(a, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(a, a - 1))
For Each cell In sums
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Split(cell.Address, "$")(1) & cell.Row - a & ":" & Split(cell.Address, "$")(1) & cell.Row))
Next
```

P.s. I take chance to highlight you a couple of things in your proposed code for the problem:

```
Set Range(ActiveCell + i, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).Value = "=SUM(R[-a]C:R[-1]C)"
```

1) Don't use the keyword `Set`, that one is for setting a variable to an object (not a string into a cell, for that you don't need anything);

2) The `ActiveCell`, without any other specification, will return by default the property `Value`. So, if you have just filled the range `A1:A4`, the line of code:

```
Range(ActiveCell + i, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
```

will not be the expected

```
Range("A5")
```

but rather a mixture of random numbers as well as syntax errors (just to give you an idea, it will be something like `Range(76,5)`).

**EDIT - if you want to insert the Excel functions instead of the hard-coded results**

```
Set sums = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(a, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(a, a - 1))
For Each cell In sums
    cell.Value = "=SUM(" & Split(cell.Address, "$")(1) & cell.Row - a & ":" & Split(cell.Address, "$")(1) & cell.Row - 1 & ")"
Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works nicely! 
But Is there a way to show the function in the cell when the user activate it in the sheet?

Comment: Thank you very much! Very precise, and thanks for the note too. 
I'm just getting back to using vba it's been a while so i still make mistakes and all. with work it will pass :) thanks

Comment: Anyway to re use the same to sum up every row this time, and get the result in the column just on the right? I'm trying to understand the split and cell.adress functions you used, tried changing the order and all but i'm still stuck

Comment: edit: I'm using this currently 
    cell.Value = "=SUM(" & cell.Column - a & Split(cell.Address, "$")(2) & ":" & cell.Column - 1 & Split(cell.Address, "$")(2) & ")"

Comment: @MrJ1m, if you're stuck in a new purpose please open another question, it will be easier and allow other people to contribute as well.